# How to put many Textbox in one If else statement

Tags: vb.net

This is the question
=If the FN button
will be click, then it will display a message base on the status of the textbox1 control. For the MN button, if
the event is click then it will display a message base on the status of the textbox2 control. The LN button
was clicked then it will display a message base on the status of the textbox3 control. Lastly, if the Clear
button control will be click and any of the textbox control is not empty then it will clear all the textbox
controls, but if all textbox controls are empty then it will show a message that all textbox controls are empty.

## this is my code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        Label1.Text = "First Name"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
        Label2.Text = "Middle Name"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click
        Label3.Text = "Last Name"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Text = "FN"
        If TextBox1.Text = vbNullString Then
            MessageBox.Show("The First name is empty")
        Else MessageBox.Show("The First name is " & TextBox1.Text)

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Button2.Text = "MN"
        If TextBox2.Text = vbNullString Then
            MessageBox.Show("The Middle name is empty")
        Else : MessageBox.Show("The Middle name is " & TextBox2.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Button3.Text = "LN"
        If TextBox3.Text = vbNullString Then
            MessageBox.Show("The Last name is empty")
        Else : MessageBox.Show("The Last name is " & TextBox3.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Button4.Text = "Clear"
        If (TextBox1.Text) And (TextBox2.Text) = vbNullString Then
            MessageBox.Show("Textbox control is empty")
        Else : TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
        For Each txt As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            txt.Text = ""
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

My question is , how to  work on clear button because i cant do it in Textbox2 and Textbox3  thankyou

Comment: Please consider: 1) Why do you set the text of the button, **when the user clicks on it**, Should it not have the text already before? 2) There are, I guess, more than one text box. So why are you checking only the first? 3) Your loop should visit all textboxes in turn and if any contains text, then the text should be removed. After the loop you can show the message.

Comment: What kind of text box controls and even buttons are you talking about? That kind of control event arguments for a button look strange to me. In VB6 and VBA it should be simple `Private Sub Button4_Click()`...

Comment: so how to put 3 textbox before the messagesbox.show appear?

Comment: So, did you see my question? Do you know what application are you talking about? What `vb6` tag should mean?

Comment: Ok, now your post looks better, but please respond to @FaneDuru. Still, why are you setting the texts of the buttons in respective buttons `Click` event? Did you not set the text already when you placed the buttons on the form? Then to the `Button4_Click`. As the purpose is to clear all text boxes anyway, you can simply clear all of them, and then show the message.

Comment: @FaneDuru this is Vb6.0

Comment: @TomBrunberg this is the what i want on button 4 now just only to clear contents of my textbox but  if the Clear button control will be click and any of the textbox control is not empty then it will clear all the textbox controls, but if all textbox controls are empty then it will show a message that all textbox controls are empty.   how to do this  thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
        CType(ctrl, TextBox).Text = String.Empty
    End If
Next ctrl
```

Try to add `Next txt` to your `For Each`

Comment: Set the name of your buttons after you drag it from your toolbox via Properties Windows, just look for the property `Name`. It is confusing to set it via code unless your buttons has more than one function, e.g. Edit & Cancel

Answer (score 1):

So, you are asking about `Button4_Click`.

This is what I was about to suggest first, because clearing all text boxes whether they are empty or not, is faster than first checking and then clearing.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
'    Button4.Text = "Clear"
'   If (TextBox1.Text) And (TextBox2.Text) = vbNullString Then
'       MessageBox.Show("Textbox control is empty")
'    Else : TextBox1.Clear()
'    End If
    For Each txt As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
        txt.Text = ""
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Textbox controls are empty")
End Sub
```

But then, if the intention is to a) just clear all textboxes, without any message if any one has some text. b) show the message only if all are empty.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
  '  Button4.Text = "Clear"

    If (TextBox1.Text = vbNullString) And (TextBox2.Text = vbNullString) And (TextBox3.Text = vbNullString) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Textbox controls are empty")
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
    End If
    
    or (if this works, VB6 is alien for me)
    
    ....
    Else
        For Each txt As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
            txt.Text = ""
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [List(Of TextBox)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.5.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.List%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) allowing you to leverage [All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.5.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.All);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue) and [ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.5.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.List%601.ForEach);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private TBs As New List(Of TextBox)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TBs.AddRange({TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3})
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        If TBs.All(Function(tb) tb.Text = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("All TextBoxes are empty!")
        Else
            TBs.ForEach(Sub(tb) tb.Clear())
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
'  Button4.Text = "Clear"

```
If (TextBox1.Text = vbNullString) And (TextBox2.Text = vbNullString) And (TextBox3.Text = vbNullString) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Textbox controls are empty")
Else
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
End If
```

thanks sir Tom Brunberg, this code works for me :)

Comment: Instead of repeating an answer as your own, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers about accepting and voting on answers.